# How can I remove an attribute from Json array

Tags: java, json, parsing, apache-httpclient-4.x

My code is below in brief :

```
private void havayı_gösterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        
        String WEATHER_URL = "https://api.collectapi.com/weather/getWeather?data.lang=tr&data.city="+şehir_ismi.getText();  

       
        //REQUEST GÖNDERME
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .header("authorization", "apikey myapikey")
                .uri(URI.create(WEATHER_URL))
                .build();

        //REQUESTE CEVAP
        
        
        try {            
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            String content = response.body();
             JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
              Object obj;
              
              obj = parser.parse(content);
              
              JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
              array.add(obj);
              
           
            
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String req_result = gson.toJson(array.get(0));
         
              
            
            String text;
                text = req_result.replaceAll("\"", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\{", "")
                        .replaceAll("result:", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\},", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\,", "")
                        .replaceAll("\\]","")
                        .replaceAll("\\[","")
                        .replaceAll("success: true","")
                        .replaceAll("\\}","");
                havayı_listele.setText(text);
```

I want to show a pretty printed data in the java swing, but attribute "icon" causes unreadability. Also Java does not support svg files. What's the easiest way to get rid of this problem ? Here is my screenshot :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5t3.png]

Comment: Do not use regex. Parse the json to Objects remove the data and create a new json

Comment: Are you getting the list of attributes inside the array(JSONArray)? If so, you can filter out icon out of it.

Comment: @PrateekJha I can print the attributes but array.remove("icon") is not working

Comment: It seems that you want to transform the response JSON string into some kind of key-value pairs. Instead of using RegEx, a better way is to deserialize the response to a `Map` then remove the `icon` key-value pair if it exists, finally convert the `Map` to a `String` as your screenshot.